# How to play sounds at set times per day, like an alarm, but only once per time and with no need to interact?

Tags: alarm, clock

I have tried Alarm Clock Xtreme which alleges to do this (play alarm, and dismiss automatically after 1s, which is the length of the sound) but it doesn't actually dismiss and just keeps looping. What other options do I have?

Use case: play one.m4a at 01:00, three.m4a at 03:00, etc. to twentythree.m4a at 23:00, every day. Each file is one second long and should be played exactly once, and preferably with no popups.

Comment: Isn't some automation tool like IFTTT sufficient for this?

Comment: Have you considered using an automation app for this? MacroDroid has an action called Play Sound where you can select your file. The Triggers can be time of day. You can setup wait and repeat actions as well.

Comment: MacroDroid appears to do the job. Thank you. :)